# select value from max datetime, for a range of datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have the following SQL Server table:

```
| InDate                  | ID     |  Value | Value2 | Value3    |
+-------------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+ 
| 2014-09-30 13:55:28.000 | 66     | 50     |      1 |         0 |
| 2014-09-30 10:05:36.000 | 66     | 60     |      2 |         0 | 
| 2014-10-01 08:31:21.000 | 66     | 20     |      3 |         0 |
| 2014-10-01 06:20:41.000 | 66     | 30     |      4 |         0 |
```

I try to create a query that takes the `Value` and the `SUM` for `Value2` and `Value3` for every max `InDate`

So I want to end up with

```
2014-09-30 13:55:28.000 | 66     | 50   | 1
2014-10-01 08:31:21.000 | 66     | 20   | 3
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    MAX(InDate),
    MAX(Value),
    SUM (Value2 + Value3) AS valueSum
FROM  
    mytable
WHERE
    ID = 66
    AND CAST(InDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-09-30' AND '2014-10-01'  
GROUP BY 
    CAST(InDate AS DATE)
```

But this returns mixed results, the max `Date`, the max `Value`, regardless of `Date` and doubles (?) the `SUM` . So, I get

```
2014-09-30 13:55:28.000 | 66     | 60   | 4
2014-10-01 08:31:21.000 | 66     | 30   | 8
```

This is wrong.

How can I get the results I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want filtering . . . like this:

```
select t.*, (value2 + value3)
from t
where t.indate = (select max(t2.indate)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and convert(date, t2.indate) = convert(date, t.indate)
                 ) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc8fc925f5a6631bd131d6d22eff35fd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tested it and it does not work as expected. Also, you dont take into account a date range

Comment: @codebot . . . It returns **exactly** what you specify you want for the calculation (albeit with some extra columns).  Something is wrong with your testing.  You should withdraw the downvote, if it is yours.